# Ruby word array as hash?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Ruby has something called a word array

```
fruits = %w(Apple Orange Melon)
```

becomes

```
fruits = ["Apple", "Orange", "Melon"]
```

is there anyway I can also use Ruby's word array as a hash?

`fruits["Apple"]` would return 0, `fruits["Orange"]` 1 and so forth. Or do I have to declare this as a hash?

```
fruits_hash = {
  'Apple' => 0,
  'Orange' => 1,
  'Melon' => 2,
}
```

The objective is to be able to save a field as a integer, but to have it's representation as a string on Rails.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
Hash[%w(Apple Orange Melon).each_with_index.to_a]  
# => {"Apple"=>0, "Orange"=>1, "Melon"=>2}
```

Comment: I like this one better.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another one:

```
fruits = %w(Apple Orange Melon)
fruit_hash = Hash[[*fruits.each_with_index]]
```

Answer (score 5):

You don't actually need `Hash` for your case. The hashes are needed in different cases, eg. to express data like:

```
{ Apple: :Rosaceae,
  Orange: :Rutaceae,
  Melon: :Cucurbitaceae } # botanical family
```

or

```
{ Apple: 27,
  Orange: 50,
  Melon: 7 } # the listing of greengrocer's stock
```

You don't need `Hash`es that simply express order, like `{ Apple: 1, Orange: 2, Melon: 3 }` -- plain array `[ :Apple, :Orange, :Melon ]` is good enough:

```
a = :Apple, :Orange, :Melon
a.index :Orange #=> 1
```

Also, I would encourage you to give a bit more consideration to sometimes using `Symbol` rather than `String`, especially for things like apple, orange, melon. Strings are for things like tweets, message bodies, goods descriptions...

```
{ Apple: "Our apples are full of antioxidants!",
  Orange: "Our oranges are full of limonene and vitamin C!",
  Melon: "Our melons are sweet and crisp!" }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Hash[fruits.zip((0...fruits.length).to_a)]
=> {"Apple"=>0, "Orange"=>1, "Melon"=>2}
```